# Information mining from Twitter using R tool

Tags: r, twitter, oauth

While making the hand-shake with Twitter API,
I am getting some error like this:

```
twitCred <- OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey=consumerKey,
+                              
+                              consumerSecret=consumerSecret,
+                              requestURL=requestURL,
+                              accessURL=accessURL,
+                              authURL=authURL)
> 
> twitCred$handshake(cainfo="cacert.pem")
To enable the connection, please direct your web browser to: 
https:/api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=lio2StTSAjSHH8jie1TgpdtgeLKuS9TS
When complete, record the PIN given to you and provide it here: 2960112

setup_twitter_oauth(consumerKey,consumerSecret,accessToken,accessScret)
[1] "Using direct authentication"
Use a local file to cache OAuth access credentials between R sessions?
1: Yes
2: No

Selection: 1
Adding .httr-oauth to .gitignore
Error in file(con, "w") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "w") : cannot open file '.gitignore': Permission denied.
```

Can anyone help me how to solve this error:

```
Error in file(con, "w") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "w") : cannot open file '.gitignore': Permission denied.
```

Thanks.

Comment: try to change your R working directory using `setwd("new_directory")`, looks like you are trying to write in a protected directory.

Comment: Thank you Sir... got the solution and now getting the tweets..     very-very Thanks Sir .   @NicE